# Add header to EndpointAddress

Tags: c#

Is there any way to add a header to EndpointAddress?

I tried this:

```
    public static ChannelFactory<IClass> CreateFactory()
    {
        var authorization = new Authorization()
        {
            Key = "test"
        };
        AddressHeader header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(authorization);

        var address = new EndpointAddress(ClientConfig.Endpoint, header);
        var channel = new ChannelFactory<IClass>(address.ResolveBinding(), address);
        return channel;
    }
```

For some reason  `new EndpointAddress` is not working bacause it cant understand header

> (the best overloaded method match for 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress.EndpointAddress(System.Uri, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)' has some invalid arguments.)

Without header everything is ok.

What I am doing wrong? I cant understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the [official documentation of EndpointAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress.aspx) you can see this class won't accept a single EndpointAddress in its constructor, but an array of EndpointAdress-objects.

So you should try:

```
AddressHeader header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(authorization);
var address = new EndpointAddress(ClientConfig.Endpoint, new[] { header });
```

Comment: Nope. The problem didn't changed. EndpointAddress should have public EndpointAddress(Uri uri, EndpointIdentity identity, params AddressHeader[] addressHeaders); but it simply didn't work or I still missing something.

Comment: How did you change the initialization of your EndpointAddress? What exception are you getting now?

Comment: Still the same exception as in my question. I  tried your advise, nothing changed :(

Comment: Hm... I think I get it. Adding header to EndpointAddres requires System.Uri, but ClientConfig.Endpoint is string...

Comment: If your `ClientConfig.Endpoint` is a string representing a URI, then simply instantiate a new URI-object. Refer to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx).
I assumed `ClientConfig.Endpoint` is already a valid URI-object. The documentation of EndpointAddress (see my answer) clearly states which constructors you may call!